# comm.Scatter KeyError with mpi4py

Tags: python, mpi4py

I'm new to MPI and mpi4py. I have two issues with the following code. For one, the data on rank 0 does not print, whereas the None type data on the other ranks do.

Second, I am getting a KeyError '0' error from the comm.Scatter() function, which I cannot explain.

```
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

if rank == 0:
    df = pickle.load(open('lipad0406.p', 'rb'))
else:
    df = None

p = size

d = np.array(df)

n = d.size

m = n/p

d_loc = np.zeros(m)

comm.Scatter(d,d_loc)

print "process", rank, "x:", d
print "process", rank, "x_local:", d_loc.size
```

Answer (score 2):

While I cannot reproduce your particular error, the problem here is that on non-root ranks `d` is an error with a single element `None`, hence `n=1` and `m` will be bogus. If you don't know the size on non-root ranks, you need to broadcast it first:

```
if rank == 0:
    df = pickle.load(open('lipad0406.p', 'rb'))
    d = np.array(df, dtype=float)
    m = d.size / size
    comm.bcast(m)
else:
    d = None
    m = comm.bcast(None)

d_loc = np.zeros(m, dtype=float)

comm.Scatter(d,d_loc)
```

Also make sure the data types match.

Answer (score 0):

The `KeyError` is happening because `Scatter` can't handle whatever data type is being loaded from your input file.

Mpi4py provides two kinds of communication functions, those whose names begin with an upper-case letter, e.g. `Scatter`, and those whose names begin with a lower-case letter, e.g. `scatter`. [From the Mpi4py documentation:](http://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/usrman/mpi4py.html)

> In MPI for Python, the Bcast(), Scatter(), Gather(), Allgather() and Alltoall() methods of Comm instances provide support for collective communications of memory buffers. The variants bcast(), scatter(), gather(), allgather() and alltoall() can communicate generic Python objects.

What is not clear from this is that even though numpy arrays supposedly expose memory buffers, the buffers apparently need to be to one of a small set of primitive data types, and certainly don't work with generic objects. Compare the following two pieces of code:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy

Comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
Size = Comm.Get_size()
Rank = Comm.Get_rank()

if Rank == 0:
    Data = numpy.empty(Size, dtype=object)
else:
    Data = None

Data = Comm.scatter(Data, 0) # I work fine!

print("Data on rank %d: " % Rank, Data)
```

and

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy

Comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
Size = Comm.Get_size()
Rank = Comm.Get_rank()

if Rank == 0:
    Data = numpy.empty(Size, dtype=object)
else:
    Data = None

Datb = numpy.empty(1, dtype=object)

Comm.Scatter(Data, Datb, 0) # I throw KeyError!

print("Datb on rank %d: " % Rank, Datb)
```

You should just be able to use `scatter` in your code with no additional modification:

```
d_loc = comm.scatter(d)
```

or eliminate `d_loc` entirely, since `scatter` does not need a separate receiving buffer like `Scatter` does, and just use

```
d = comm.scatter(d)
```

Additionally, as Zulan has said, you need to make sure that the `dtype`s of your numpy arrays `d` and `d_loc` match and that `m` is broadcast to the non-rank-0 processes.

Running your code exactly except with `df = pickle.load(open('lipad0406.p', 'rb'))` replaced by `df = range(size)`, since I don't have and cannot much conjecture about the contents of your file, does not fail to print `d` in the rank-0 process, so I can only conjecture that that particular problem has something to do with loading the file.

The minimally modified working version of your code, the file loading excepted, is

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

if rank == 0:
    df = range(size)
else:
    df = None

p = size

d = np.array(df)

n = d.size

m = comm.bcast(n/p)

d_loc = np.zeros(m)

d_loc = comm.scatter(d)

print "process", rank, "x:", d
print "process", rank, "x_local:", d_loc.size
```